Setting org-todo-keywords breaks agenda functionality
TLDR: Setting org-todo-keywords has broken org-agenda for me. How can I set this variable without the negative side-effects?
I am encountering three issues with org-agenda:

When I invoke an org-agenda view that includes alltodo, or just pull up the all TODO view with t, no items show up. The only way I can get items to appear on the agenda is if I use a daily/weekly view and the items are scheduled in that time.
Though I have a set of org-todo-keywords defined and C-h v on that variable shows the value I expect, attempting to cycle through TODO states in either the actual .org files or the agenda view will only progress through TODO, DONE, and an keyword-less state.
When I set org-agenda-custom-commands that use org-super-agenda-groups, org-agenda does not respect these. No items that match the filters I've defined appear on the agenda, nor are any headings shown.

In my current configuration, if I set debug-on-entry for org-agenda-get-todos, then when I invoke the 'All TODOs' view (org-agenda + t), I see the following backtrace:
* org-agenda-get-todos()
  org-agenda-get-day-entries("/home/myUser/path/to/org/agenda.org" (6 29 2024) :todo)
  org-todo-list(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-todo-list nil)
  call-interactively(org-todo-list)
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda nil nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda)

It wasn't clear to me from this what the problem might be, but I thought there was something amiss in its only calling org-agenda-get-day-entries on one file. I tried to copy all of my TODO items to agenda.org from inbox.org, but this did not fix the issue at all.
So I decided to attempt a differential diagnosis. I booted up Emacs with the default settings. I set the following:
(setq org-directory (expand-file-name "~/path/to/org")) and booted up org-agenda. It successfully pulls up all the non-done TODO items in inbox.org. I experimented with copying some of these to other files in the directory, and it catches them all. So far, so good.
Next, I had a suspicion that the occasional message warning me of an org version conflict might have something to do with it, so in my scratch buffer I add the following configuration in, to mirror what I have in my main configuration:
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
     (expand-file-name
      "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el"
      (or (bound-and-true-p straight-base-dir)
          user-emacs-directory)))
    (bootstrap-version 7))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radian-software/straight.el/develop/install.el"
       'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))

(straight-use-package 'use-package)
(setq straight-use-package-by-default t)

(use-package org)

After I use straight-pull-all and eval-buffer, org-version returns 9.6.15, while my main config returns 9.8-pre. The All TODOs view still works in the scratch config at this point.
Next, I add in more of my current agenda-related config:
(setq org-agenda-files
      (mapcar 'file-truename
          (file-expand-wildcards
           (concat org-directory "/*.org")))
      org-agenda-hide-tags-regexp "."
      org-agenda-prefix-format
      '((agenda . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s")
        (todo . " ")
        (tags . "%i %-12:c")
        (search . "%i %-12:c"))
      org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence
         "TRIAGE(t)"
         "BACKLOG(b)"
         "READY FOR WORK(r)"
         "TODAY(o)"
         "REVIEW(v)"
         "DONE(d)"))
      org-log-done 'time)

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c a") 'org-agenda)

After applying these changes, everything still works just fine.
I add org-super-agenda and enable the mode:
(use-package org-super-agenda
  :init
  (org-super-agenda-mode))

And again, everything's working fine. Now, I add one of my org-super-agenda-based custom commands:
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("p" "Personal Agenda"
     ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 'day)
              (org-super-agenda-groups
               '((:name "Today"
                  :time-grid t
                  :date today
                  :todo "TODAY"
                  :scheduled today
                  :order 1)))))
      (alltodo "" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "")
               (org-super-agenda-groups
             '((:name "Inbox"
                :tag "inbox"
                :order 1)
             (:name "Important"
                :priority "A"
                :order 2)
             (:name "Due Today"
                :deadline today
                :order 3)
             (:name "Overdue"
                :deadline past
                :order 4)
             (:name "Easy Wins"
                :tag "easy"
                :order 5))))))))

Now, at this stage what happens is that C-c a t for the all TODOs view still pulls in everything successfully, but if I enter C-c a p for the Personal Agenda view I've defined, the only part that works at all is the daily agenda block at the top. The alltodo section is utterly empty.
I remove all the org-super-agenda-groups definitions from the alltodo section so that the custom command looks like this:
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("p" "Personal Agenda"
     ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 'day)
              (org-super-agenda-groups
               '((:name "Today"
                  :time-grid t
                  :date today
                  :todo "TODAY"
                  :scheduled today
                  :order 1)))))
      (alltodo "")))))

Now the pane below the agenda at least shows the title Global list of TODO items of type: ALL, but it still doesn't show any entries, even though I know the correct files are being read because there ARE entries in the day-agenda pane. Even if I reduce the Personal Agenda view to JUST (alltodo ""), it still doesn't grab anything.
Just to sanity-check, I try calling C-c a t again and now THAT is also not working, but now all of my org-todo-keywords are being respected. org-version is still reporting 9.6.15 for this scratch instance.
After further experimentation, adding and removing things, it turns out that the source of every problem was this:
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence
         "TRIAGE(t)"
         "BACKLOG(b)"
         "READY FOR WORK(r)"
         "TODAY(o)"
         "REVIEW(v)"
         "DONE(d)")))

Removing this and this alone makes the agenda behave exactly how I want it to, except that I now can't use the keyword rotation I want.

"I have verified that, given this configuration, org-agenda-files evaluates to the directory where the various files that I want to feed my agenda live" - it's probably irrelevant to your question, but that's not true: both the variable org-agenda-files and the function of the same name should evaluate to a list of all .org files in your org-directory. Check that inbox.org is a member of that list.

I think the syntax of FILETAGS requires the colons: #+FILETAGS: :inbox: - see Tag Inheritance in the manual. But I don't know if this will fix your problem. - After checking, no, this is wrong:  it works either way.

Imprecise language on my part: org-agenda-files does indeed evaluate to a list of all .org files in org-directory, and inbox.org is a member of that list.

If you are checking with C-c a a you have to make sure that there is a timestamp (plain, scheduled, or deadline) on the items that you expert to appear, and the timestamp has to be within the span of the agenda. If you are doing C-c a t, they show whether there is a timestamp or not. So AFAICT things work as they should. If it still does not work for you, please provide a step-by-step recipe that I can follow to try to reproduce your problem.
